# Spring Batch Admin Webapp fails to stop jobs, sending a Http POST instead of DELETE

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

When trying to stop a job from within the spring-batch-admin webapp (version 1.3.0) the follwing error page appears:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Sep 04 17:57:05 CEST 2014
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'POST' not supported
```

The controller expects a DELETE method to stop the job, but from the stop button a POST is triggered. Does anyone know how to fix that?

[image]

**EDIT:** I did some further research and stumbled upon a three years old post from the [**spring forum**](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/101647-batch-admin-post-not-supported-error). It suggests that I am probably missing a `HiddenMethodFilter` in my web.xml. As I integrated the batch-admin into a spring boot application there might be a configuration issue. Now I just need to figure out how to add the afromentioned filter to my spring-boot-mvc defaults.

**EDIT:** I gradually understand better what's going on under the hood. I asked a more specific question to my problem [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25670840/adding-a-filter-to-the-servlet-configuration-in-spring-boot).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My servlet configuration was missing the following beans:

```
import org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter;
import org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter;

@Bean
public Filter shallowEtagHeaderFilter() {
  ShallowEtagHeaderFilter filter = new ShallowEtagHeaderFilter();
  return filter; 
}

@Bean
public Filter hiddenHttpMethodFilter() {
  HiddenHttpMethodFilter filter = new HiddenHttpMethodFilter();      
  return filter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The same filters can be configured via the web.xml like this

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>shallowEtagHeaderFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.ShallowEtagHeaderFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>shallowEtagHeaderFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```